# Issue with parsing .html page with callbackWrapper function

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to extract all the 'id' in the json like structure which looks like this:

```
callbackWrapper({

    "scoreboard": [
    {
        "day":"",
        "games":[
        {
             "id":"2433023",
             "lastUpdated":"1518108600",
             "updatedTimestamp":"2018-02-08 11:50:45",
             "conference":"all-conf southland northeast",
             "gameState":"final",
             "startDate":"2017-03-14",
             "startDateDisplay":"Mar. 14",
             "startTime":"6:40 PM ET",
             "startTimeEpoch":"1489531200",
             "currentPeriod":"",
             "finalMessage":"Final",
      etc....
```

I have the following in my nodejs js file:

```
request({

    url: url,
    json: true

}, function (error, response, body) {

    try {

        var mmSchedule = body;

        console.log(mmSchedule) // PRINT THE PAGE CONTENTS

        for (var i = 0; i < body["scoreboard"]["games"].length; i++) {

            console.log("lenght: ", mmSchedule["scoreboard"]["games"].length); <--- DOESNT WORK!!!

        }

    }

}
```

I am trying to read the "id" in the array under 'scoreboard' - 'day' - 'games' but I keep getting undefined !?

What am I missing?

Comment: `scoreboard` is an array of objects. You need one more loop to loop over that, or if you have only one item in array you can just use `body["scoreboard"][0]["day"]["games"].length`

Comment: That is not working... and there will be multiple 'id' in the file.

Comment: according to your json structure , you will get id of games : body.scoreboard[0].games[0].id , your id will not come under day, its in games

Comment: Error is thrown "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: Hi @Learn2Code, Can you please show me your code what you have written at this moment "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" getting this error.